# If $K$ is finite, then every subset of $\mathbb A^n(K)$ is algebraic

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to prove that if $K$ is a finite field, then every subset of $\mathbb A^n(K)$ is algebraic. I know that if $K$ is finite, then every element of $K$ is algebraic, i.e., for every $a\in K$ there is a polynomial $f\in K$ such that $f(a)=0$, but this didn't help me to solve the question. I almost sure that we have to use this to solve this question.

I need help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By the way, any field (even infinite fields) is algebraic over itself :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A finite union of algebraic sets is an algebraic set.

Comment: since $K$ is finite, then every subset of $\mathbb A^n$ is finite, so algebraic, am I right?

Comment: Exactly. In general, any finite subset of affine space is algebraic.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a another approach, I'll give you a hint. Show that every map $K^n\to K$ is a polynomial. Begin by showing that you can write the indicator function at any point as a polynomial (remember you can find a polynomial that has, as roots, any subset of $K$). Then, just add up appropriate multiples of these indicator functions.